# If $G$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix and $G^5=0$ (assuming $G \ne 0$), is $G$ always invertible, never invertible, or sometimes invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

I think the answer is that it is never invertible but I don't really know how to prove it. Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: $\det(G)^5 = \det(G^5) = \det(0) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** how can you use your relation if $G$ has an inverse $A$?